# How to override ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

We have a spring boot webflux app running as microservices architecture on k8s environment. It will be scale up/down automatically by k8s runtime.

We need to generate a unique ID for each instance of the app when it is created and started by k8s (by scaling up). Then we can use this ID as a part of Kafka topic to subscribe to. I found a way is to register a custom `ApplicationContextInitializer` to spring.factories, but I cannot find a way to remove/replace the existing `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer`.

Both classes are loaded when spring start the app. So my question is: How to replace the `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` with my implementation?
Or more straightforward, how to generate unique spring ID/name on k8s runtime?

PS: no eureka usage

Comment: Why not just set `spring.application.name` as that is used as the id.

Comment: Is it possible on k8s environment? Our app will be scaled up/down automatically by k8s runtime. Can we configure k8s to random a `name` and set it to an env variable?

Comment: Please describe what your usecase is. Your question was about changing the id, which is bound to the name. The question nowhere mentions K8S. Why do you need the context-id to be different in the first place? Feels like you are using it for something you shouldn't be using it for.

Comment: Still doesn't explain the use-case. What are you doing with the id? Why does it need to be different? Also the `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` runs at a low, if you lets yours run after it you can override/append to the generated ID. But I'm a bit worried what you are trying to do with that.

Comment: Updated again. It is used for Kafka topic. Btw I don't want to let `ContextIdApplicationContextInitializer` run, then my class run on top of it. It waste resource. But if there is no way, I need to implement that way

Comment: It is loaded automatically so unless you trash the `spring.factories` it won't be excluded. But why use the application context id for this, why not a dedicated property which you manage yourself?

Comment: You are right, I think I need to use my own property. Thank you

Comment: Could you describe your Kafka use case in more details. Is it about  `group.instance.id`?

Comment: basically we need to create one kafka consumer subscribing to one topic per instance. Ex: if k8s scale up to 10 instance then we have 10 kafka topic for each instance to subscribe to.

The flow is: a HTTP request come to a instance, then it asynchronously sends message to another service, then waiting the response asynchronously (we put HTTP session to "await" mode by CountDownLatch, then wake it up when response come and return the HTTP response). We need one topic per instance to make sure responses are delivered correctly to "source" instance)

The topic: my.topic${instance.id}
@Alex

Comment: Waw. Sounds a bit complex. But how unique Id would help you? Eventually you could create infinite number of  topics and synchronization could be not easy as well. Not sure I understand the problem but did you consider using partitions instead and leveraging custom partition logic for kafka topics?